# How do i run java from a different directory?

Tags: java, bash

I have the java files and the input files in directory B and I need to run it from directory A. How can I do this?

I tried with the absolute path

*/usr/java/jre1.7.0_45/bin/java -classpath  /home/usrname/A/B/bin/ -Xmx1900M LB*

but it searches for the input files in the directory A instead of B.

in the case of a C executable I type

*(cd /home/usrname/A/B && ./Cexec)*

And it works

Comment: Have you considered passing the base path in program parameters? Or maybe if they are static resources have you considered moving them to classpath?

Comment: I cant do that, but I find the way, newbie way
(cd /home/usrname/A/B &&  /usr/java/jre1.7.0_45/bin/java -classpath ./bin/ -Xmx1900M LB)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do for Java what you did for C?

```
(cd /home/usrname/A/B && /usr/java/jre1.7.0_45/bin/java -classpath bin -Xmx1900M LB)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved

(cd /home/usrname/A/B && /usr/java/jre1.7.0_45/bin/java -classpath ./bin/ -Xmx1900M LB)